# How do I use WP_Query for a custom post type of a specific taxonomy?

Tags: html, wordpress, slider, custom-post-type

I have a slide custom post type and I need to be able to create a query for a selected tag of this custom post type so I can create a group of these custom slider post types to show up in the slider.  So far I can't figure it out.

Comment: That's what we're here for. Why don't you show us the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: You can retrieve the tag_id using `get_query_var('tad_id');`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    "post_type" => "yourposttype",
    "tag" => "yourtagName"
));
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    //code goes here
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'music',
    'musician'    => 'Adele, Avril Lavigne',
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

change "music" to your post_type name, "musician" to your taxonomy name, "adele" to your category name

Comment: The problem I have is that my select field on the options passes the custom post type's taxonomy variable as a number not as a slug.  So i have '4' instead of 'Adele'.